# Lost Power During apt-get install, Can't Resolve Missing Dependencies

Tags: power, aptitude, apt-get, dependencies

I tried to install `mercurial` today, and the power went out. Now, when I try to install any packages, it complains about a couple of different things:

```
>$ sudo apt-get install mercurial 
[sudo] password: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mercurial is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
hunspell-en-us : Conflicts: 
openoffice.org-core (<= ) but 1:3.2.1-7ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' 
with no packages (or specify a solution).
>$ hg
The program 'hg' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install mercurial
>$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  hunspell-en-us
Suggested packages:
  hunspell
The following packages will be upgraded:
  hunspell-en-us
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/249kB of archives.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
warning, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 10469 package 'hunspell-en-us':
 `Conflicts' field, reference to `openoffice.org-core':
 `<' is obsolete, use `<=' or `<<' instead
warning, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 10469 package 'hunspell-en-us':
 `Conflicts' field, reference to `openoffice.org-core':
 version value starts with non-alphanumeric, suggest adding a space
dpkg: parse error, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' 
near line 10469 package 'hunspell-en-us':
 `Conflicts' field, reference to `openoffice.org-core': version contains ` '
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
$ sudo dpkg --purge hunspell-en-us
warning, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 10469 package 'hunspell-en-us':
 `Conflicts' field, reference to `openoffice.org-core':
 `<' is obsolete, use `<=' or `<<' instead
warning, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 10469 package 'hunspell-en-us':
 `Conflicts' field, reference to `openoffice.org-core':
 version value starts with non-alphanumeric, suggest adding a space
dpkg: parse error, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 10469 package 'hunspell-en-us':
 `Conflicts' field, reference to `openoffice.org-core': version contains ` '
```

I wish I could give you more hints...I tried going into synaptic and filtering by my broken packages...`hunspell-en-us` does come back as broken...all options fail in almost identical ways to what's posted above.

I'd appreciate any help with this. I'm worried I may have to purge/uninstall/reinstall `openoffice.org-core`, but that's a little bit too crazy to do before consulting everyone here.

I tried purging too:

```
>$ sudo apt-get purge
[sudo] password for droogans: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hunspell-en-us : Conflicts: openoffice.org-core (<= ) but 1:3.2.1-7ubuntu1.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
>$ sudo apt-get purge -f
```

This last command didn't do anything different as well.
Think it's time to uninstall openoffice, and the 15+ packages that are going down with it?

## UPDATE

I decided to try and dig myself out of a hole by selecting "Completely Remove" from synaptic for `openoffice.org-core`, and allowing it to also take its dependents with it. I was going to reinstall + update each package afterwards, but it **still** won't let me go through with it. Same error message as before, and now I'm wondering what other options I have.

Everything works fine on my computer...except getting new, updating existing, repairing or removing packages on my machine.

## RESOLVED

After running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` I got this last line, which was a new one:

```
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: acpi-support is not installed
```

Which, after a quick search, turned up [this solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1736967.html):

```
$> cd /var/lib/dpkg
$> sudo cp status-old status
$> sudo cp available-old available
$> sudo apt-get install -f
```

That cleared it up. I had to go into synaptic to get a genuine reinstall, but afterwards, it worked.

*Finally. Thanks everyone.*

Comment: What happens if you do an "apt-get purge" and then attempt again?

Comment: Are you able to post that section of the /var/lib/dpkg/status file? Perhaps there really is a squirrely value in there that's confusing things. Search some things like "dpkg status corrupt" for a bit more info.

Comment: @fencepost, you were right. I had to reset my available file as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `dpkg-reconfigure -a` helped me out of crashed updates many times. Opposed to `dpkg --configure -a` it even tries to configure packages again which already had been started to be configured.

Comment: Note: **Read my final update**. This wasn't the correct answer, but it [brought me to it](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1736967.html).

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get -f install` Should fix your problem.

Comment: Care to explain why that should work?

Comment: My bad didn't notice he already tried to do it.. Try running dpkg with -C so dpkg searches for partially installed packages and suggest what to do to get them working.

Comment: Yeah it's coming back with the exact same error...thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add a "desperation answer" since you seem urgent to fix it. You might have tried some of these things already.

- Try using `aptitude` instead of `apg-get`. It at least used to be more intelligent than `apt-get` when it came to conflict resolution, and perhaps it handles this situation differently (though nowadays there isn't much difference between the two, I've heard).
- Try `sudo aptitude purge hunspell-en-us`, or even `sudo aptitude purge openoffice.org-core` and later reinstall them.
- Download the [`hunspell-en-us` package from debian.org](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=hunspell-en-us) (or from Ubuntu, you haven't said which distribution you are using) and try to install it directly with `dpkg`.
- (Safety goggles on for this one:) Try to move the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` somewhere else and see if that will make it attempt to be rebuilt when using APT. Move it back if it just makes things worse.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` should repair your dpkg database. Then update and try installing packages

Comment: Same error listed as above. All three warnings are in `'/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 10469 package 'hunspell-en-us'`, all three are `'Conflicts' field, reference to 'openoffice.org-core'`